# How to move variables from python to template and back?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get information from a form to my python file and then put into a template. Thing is, i know the form is working but i couldn't show it into the template.

Form here:

```
    <div class="container" id="cont1">
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/areas" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="author">Autor</label>
        <input type="text" id="author" name="author"><br><br>
        <label for="intro">Introdução</label>
        <input type="text" id="intro" name="intro"><br><br>
        <label for="content">Conteúdo</label>
        <input type="text" id="content" name="content"><br><br>
        <input type="file" id="planilha" name="planilha" accept=".csv"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</div>
```

then i try to get the data in app.py:

```
    @app.route('/areas', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def areas():
if request.method == "POST":
    @app.context_processor
    def f1():
        aut = request.form.get['author']
        intr = request.form['intro']
        cont = request.form['content']
        return dict(a=aut, i=intr, c=cont)
    return render_template("areas.html")
else:
    return render_template("areas.html")
```

I know it's working because i tried it out of the route and it showed what the form had. Now when i try into the route:

AssertionError
AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late.
To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.

The decorator was the solution i found to get the data so i could place into templates like this:

```
<text>{{a}}</text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the incorrect usage of the decorator. You don't need a decorator to pass variables to templates. [`render_template`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.render_template) also accepts arguments which you can directly pass into your HTML file.

The following should work:

```py
@app.route('/areas', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def areas():
if request.method == "POST":
    aut = request.form['author']
    intr = request.form['intro']
    cont = request.form['content']
    return render_template("areas.html", a=aut, i=intr, c=cont)
else:
    return render_template("areas.html")
```

Comment: It worked but i had to remove the .get from the ['author'] line. Thanks man.

Comment: @Keeper Of course, I'm glad it helped! You're totally right I will be more meticulous next time. 
FYI - You can use `.get('author', None)` too. This would return a `None` when the key is not found instead of raising a `KeyError`.